# Keeping the max within a group constant within a group using base::cumsum

Tags: r, purrr, rolling-computation, cumsum, accumulate

Use the data below to make the `cumsum_a` column look like the `should` column.

Data to start with:

```
> demo
    th seq group
1 20.1   1    10
2 24.1   2    10
3 26.1   3    10
4  1.1   1    20
5  2.1   2    20
6  4.1   3    20
```

The "should" column below is the goal.

```
demo<-data.frame(th=c(c(20.1,24.1,26.1),(c(1.1,2.1,4.1))),
    seq=(c(1:3,1:3)),group=c(rep(10,3),rep(20,3)))

library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

demo %>% 
    group_by(group) %>%
        mutate(
    cumsum_a= cumsum((group)^seq*
            (((th)/cummax(th)))))%>%  
        ungroup()%>%
        mutate(.,
  cumsum_m=c( #As an example only, this manually does exactly what cumsum_a is doing (which is wrong)
        10^1*20.1/20.1,   #good
        10^1*20.1/20.1 + 10^2*24.1/24.1,            #different denominators, bad       
        10^1*20.1/20.1 + 10^2*24.1/24.1 + 10^3*26.1/26.1, #different denominators, bad
        20^1*1.1/1.1, #good
        20^1*1.1/1.1 + 20^2*2.1/2.1, #different denominators, bad
        20^1*1.1/1.1 + 20^2*2.1/2.1 + 20^3*4.1/4.1 #different denominators, bad
    ),
  should=c( #this is exactly the kind of calculation I want
        10^1*20.1/20.1,  #good
        10^1*20.1/24.1 + 10^2*24.1/24.1,        #good
        10^1*20.1/26.1 + 10^2*24.1/26.1 + 10^3*26.1/26.1, #good
        20^1*1.1/1.1, #good
        20^1*1.1/2.1 + 20^2*2.1/2.1, #good
        20^1*1.1/4.1 + 20^2*2.1/4.1 + 20^3*4.1/4.1 #good
    )

)
```

Most simply put, denominators need to be the same for each row so 24.1 and 24.1 instead of 20.1 and 24.1 on the second row of `cumsum_m` or the underlying calculations for `cumsum_a`.

Here are the new columns, where `should` is what `cumsum_a` or `cumsum_m` should be.

```
     th   seq group cumsum_a cumsum_m should
  <dbl> <int> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1  20.1     1    10       10       10    10 
2  24.1     2    10      110      110   108.
3  26.1     3    10     1110     1110  1100.
4   1.1     1    20       20       20    20 
5   2.1     2    20      420      420   410.
6   4.1     3    20     8420     8420  8210.
```

Comment: Here the result of `an` column is wrong you mean?

Comment: Yes it's wrong. `Should` is right (i changed the name from `an` to `cumsum_a`)

Comment: There is a `3.1` value in you last computation by hand that should be `4.1` so that your result will match mine.

Comment: Changed the `3.1` to `4.1` and the end result in `should`.

Comment: Ok very good. I will explain what I did in the solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

- `purrr::accumulate` takes a two argument function, the first one which is represented by `.x` or `..1` is the accumulated value of the previous iterations and `.y` represents the current value of our vector `(2:n())`. So our first accumulated value will be first element of `group` value as I supplied it as `.init` argument
- Since you would like to change the denominator of the previous iterations/ calculations, I multiplied the result `.x` by the ratio of the previous value of `cmax` to the current value of `cmax`

I think the rest is pretty clear but if you have any more question about it just let me know.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

demo %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(cmax = cummax(th), 
         should = accumulate(2:n(), .init = group[1], 
                             ~ (.x * cmax[.y - 1] / cmax[.y]) + (group[.y] ^ seq[.y]) * (th[.y] / cmax[.y])))

# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   group [2]
     th   seq group  cmax should
  <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1  20.1     1    10  20.1    10 
2  24.1     2    10  24.1   108.
3  26.1     3    10  26.1  1100.
4   1.1     1    20   1.1    20 
5   2.1     2    20   2.1   410.
6   4.1     3    20   4.1  8210.
```